# Google Script/JavaScript Converting time between timezones

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, timezone, google-calendar-api

I travel a lot, and I often have appointments (such as flights) that start in one timezone and end in another.  I need to know both the local and UTC time that each event will start and end.

I use Google Calendar and specify the different start and end timezones in the calendar events.

I have written a script that pulls my agenda for a given time period, which shows everything in my local time, which is fine.

I am having difficulty getting the local time.

When I retrieve the events, the time is shown in my local time.

I can retrieve the timezone in the format Europe/Rome, etc. but this doesn't help me display the local time.

Attached is a screenshot of an entry in my calendar:

[image: Google Calendar Screenshot]

And here is how the event is seen from my script (taken from the log file):

```
Start: 2017-03-29T16:35:00+01:00, startTimeZone: Europe/Berlin.
End: 2017-03-29T22:30:00+01:00, endTimeZone: Asia/Qatar
```

These times should be Start: 17:35 and End: 00:30, respectively.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to get the local time or convert between timezones?

Comment: Show a few lines of your script.  Any date code in your script uses the time zone of the script as the default.  Your script has it's own time zone that is separate from the calendar time zone.  By default the time zones are the same unless you changed them.  Where are you displaying the time from your script?  In a dialog box or sidebar?  In a spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi Sandy, thanks for replying.  I don't think I asked my question very well.  I have a date in the format `2017-03-30T01:01:00+01:00` with a timezone of `Asia/Qatar`.  I want to show the time in my spreadsheet as `03:01`, which is the time it will be in Qatar when the appointment occurs.  The time coming back from my script is in my Calendar's local time, which is fine. I need to adjust that to the timezone that the event occurs in.  It gets difficult with varying daylight savings start and end dates and rules, so I really want a way to say that `Asia/Qatar` on a given date is GMT +/- X hours.

Comment: I would start by having you look at the documentation for `Utilities.formatDate()`  That will probably handle the daylight savings issue automatically, so that you don't need to program that yourself.  [Link to Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Comment: Thanks.  This uses the three letter timezone, e.g. GMT, PST, etc.  Or it uses an offset, e.g. +6.  Unfortunately, Google Calendar users the timezone format "Asia/Qatar" (which would be "AST" or "+3").  I need to dynamically convert from one to the other :(

Comment: Do you need a list of all the time zones in the long text format?  I got a list from inspecting the HTML in the browser development tools for the calendar settings I think.  I've got that list if you think it might help.

Comment: Hi Sandy. I have the list. I need to programmatically convert from my calendar's base timezone to the time in the local timezone.  DST is a complication, especially as not all parts of a country observe it, e.g. Brisbane has no DST, but Melbourne does, so for 6 months they are in the same timezone (AEST/UTC+10) and for the other 6, Melbourne is on AEDTUTC+11, while Brisbane remains on AEST/UTC+10.  I just need to reliably get the local time as I will be in 22 different timezones this year and Google Calendar on Android isn't great for starting in one and ending in another.

Comment: I wonder if Moment js could help you:  [moment.js timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this might help you.

```
function timezones()
{
  var today = new Date();
  var hour = 3600000;
  var tz = '';
  today = new Date(today.getTime() + (13 * hour));
  var s = '<div id="mydiv">';
  for(var i = 12;  i >= -11; i--)
  {
    if(i > 0){ tz = 'GMT+' + i;}
    if(i == 0){tz = 'GMT';}
    if(i < 0){tz = 'GMT' + i;}
    today = new Date(today.getTime() - hour);
    s += '<div class="myDates">' + Utilities.formatDate(today,"GMT", "'Date:'yyyy-MM-dd' Time:'HH:mm:ss") + 'TimeZone; "' + tz + '"</div>';
  }
  s += '</div>';
  dispStatus('Timezones', s);
}
```

This is the display routine that I use.

```
function dispStatus(title,html,width,height,modal)
{
  var title = typeof(title) !== 'undefined' ? title : 'No Title Provided';
  var width = typeof(width) !== 'undefined' ? width : 400;
  var height = typeof(height) !== 'undefined' ? height : 300;
  var html = typeof(html) !== 'undefined' ? html : '<p>No html provided.</p>';
  var modal = typeof(modal) !== 'undefined' ? modal : false;
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(width)
     .setHeight(height);
 if(!modal)
 {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, title);
 }
 else
 {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, title);
 }
}
```

And [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/) is  a timezone map.

Comment: Hi Cooper.  Thanks for your reply.  I don't think I asked my question very well.  Basically, I get back a date and time in my local calendar's timezone.  The actual appointment is in another timezone, and there is a timezone property to tell me the timezone it's in.  I want to add the local time to my spreadsheet, e.g. I get `22:30` in the timezone `Asia/Qatar` and I want to show this as `00:30`, i.e. the time it will be in Qatar when the appointment occurs.

Comment: Essentially you need to add an hour for each 15 degrees in longitude to the east and subtract an hour for each 15 degrees of longitude to the west.  Take a careful look at this [map](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/) it tells the whole story.

Comment: Thanks, but having the timezone "Asia/Qatar" doesn't give me the lat/long, so I can't calculate how many degrees east or west the timezone is.  It also doesn't deal with Daylight Savings Time, which varies by country and sometimes even within countries.  I need this to work for the constant changes in my calendar, so I need a programmatic way of dynamically calculating the local time :/

Comment: So I would use [this API](https://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/time-api.html)

Comment: Thanks.  It's quite expensive, though.  I think I will have to try to build a database and run some hideous query to check each entry.  It's annoying that Google doesn't let me get the data from my Calendar, where the records are entered in local time and show the UTC offset.  If I could just get that info from the Calendar, it would be perfect :(

Comment: Here's a link to the [calendar API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/).  I haven't really done much with the calendar myself but I'll leave you a copy of what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Calendar Play</h1>
function calendarTesting()
    {

  var rngA = CalendarApp.getAllOwnedCalendars();
  var s='';
  for(var i = 0;i < rngA.length; i++)
  {
    s += '<div id="Cal' + i + '"><Strong>Name: </strong>' + rngA[i].getName();
    s += '<br /><strong>Color: </strong><span style="color:'+ 'black' +';">' + rngA[i].getColor() + '</span>';
    s += '<br /><strong>Description: </strong>' + rngA[i].getDescription();
    var pri = (rngA[i].isMyPrimaryCalendar())? 'Yes': 'No';
    s += '<br /><strong>IsMyPrimaryCalender: </strong>' + pri + '</div>';
    s += '<style>#Cal'+ i +'{background-color:'+ rngA[i].getColor() +';padding:10px;}</style>';

  }
  var now = new Date();
  var ForWeeksFromNow = new Date(now.getTime() + (28 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(now,ForWeeksFromNow);
  for(var j = 0; j < events.length; j++)
  {
    s+= '<div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px 50px 10px 10px;">';
    s += '<div style="float:right;font-size:48px;">' + Utilities.formatDate(events[j].getStartTime(),"GMT-7", "E") + '</div>';
    s += '<br /><strong>Title: </strong>' + events[j].getTitle();
    s += '<br /><strong>Start: </strong>' + Utilities.formatDate(events[j].getStartTime(),"GMT-7", "MMM dd HH:mm");
    s += '<br /><strong>End: </strong>' + Utilities.formatDate(events[j].getEndTime(), "GMT-7", "MMM dd HH:mm");
    s += '<div style="float:right;font-size:12px;">' + events[j].getDescription() + '</div>';
    s += '</div>';

  }
  s += '<br /><br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var title = 'Calendar for: ' + Utilities.formatDate(now, "GMT-7", "E MMM dd, yyyy");
  dispStatus(title, '<p>' + s + '</p>',600,500);
}

function dispStatus(title,html,width,height)
{
// Display a modeless dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  var title = typeof(title) !== 'undefined' ? title : 'No Title Provided';
  var width = typeof(width) !== 'undefined' ? width : 250;
  var height = typeof(height) !== 'undefined' ? height : 300;
  var html = typeof(html) !== 'undefined' ? html : '<p>No html provided.</p>';
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(width)
     .setHeight(height);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Cooper, but this seems to be hard coding a timezone offset (GMT-7).  I need this to work dynamically from "Europe/London" or "Asia/Qatar" or "Pacific/Tarawa" or "America/New_York" or any other timezone that a calendar event may start or end in.  Thus, it must be a generic solution that will handle any scenario - I wish I could hard code it, as life would be simple, but unfortunately my use case is dynamic.

Comment: Check out the APIs at timeanddate.com. They’re not free but they might be able to help you solve your problem.